# CKEditor + CKFinder image uploads

Tags: javascript, php, ckeditor, ckfinder

I'm using CKEditor 4.5.2 with CKFinder 3.0.0 on PHP 5.6. Generally the integration works fine - when I click the CKEditor image button, I can click the "Browse server" button and CKFinder opens, I can select images, and also do uploads.

What doesn't work is the 'Upload' tab in the image2 dialogue. I always get an error saying "The requested resource type is not valid." when I click the "Send to server" button.

In my CKFinder config I have two resource types defined called `Images` and `Library`; these are essentialy the same except that `Library` is read-only - I only want to allow uploads to the `Images` type.

There are multiple ways of configuring the integration between CKEditor and CKFinder. I am using a custom JS config file for CKEditor and connecting ckFinder to it using the `setupCKEditor` method, as per [the docs](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_file_browse_upload-section-example-6-%26mdash%3B-ckfinder-integration-using-ckfinder.setupckeditor%28%29):

```
CKFinder.setupCKEditor(ckeditor_1, {
    'height': '100%',
    'jquery': '/js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js',
    'skin': 'jquery-mobile',
    'swatch': 'a',
    'themeCSS': '/themes/mytheme.min.css',
    'filebrowserBrowseUrl': '/ckfinder/ckfinder.html',
    'filebrowserImageBrowseUrl': '/ckfinder/ckfinder.html?Type=Images',
    'filebrowserImageUploadUrl':  '/ckfinder/core/connector/php/connector.php?command=QuickUpload&type=Images'
}, "Images");
```

I've tried passing the same values to CKEditor in my `CKEDITOR.replace` call, and also set them on the `config` property in my external config file, yet nothing changes - I still get the same error.

How should I do this? Alternatively, since the CKFinder uploader works fine, how can I disable the upload tab in the image2 dialogue?

Update: here's my current code for creating CKEditor and CKFinder instances:

```
var ckeditor_1 = CKEDITOR.replace('html', {
    "baseHref":"http://mysite.mac.local/",
    "toolbarStartupExpanded":true,
    "extraPlugins":"symbol",
    "customConfig":"/js/ckconfig.js"
});
CKFinder.setupCKEditor( ckeditor_1, {
    'height': '100%',
    'jquery': '/js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js',
    'skin': 'jquery-mobile',
    'swatch': 'a',
    'themeCSS': '/themes/mytheme.min.css'
}, { type: "Images" } );
```

And my CKEditor config file:

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function (config) {

    // Define changes to default configuration here. For example:
    // config.language = 'fr';
    // config.uiColor = '#AADC6E';
    config.docType = '<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">';
    config.toolbarGroups = [
        {name: 'document', groups: ['mode', 'document', 'doctools']},
        {name: 'clipboard', groups: ['clipboard', 'undo']},
        {name: 'editing', groups: ['find', 'selection', 'spellchecker']},
        {name: 'links'},
        {name: 'insert'},
        {name: 'tools'},
        {name: 'others'},
        '/',
        {name: 'basicstyles', groups: ['basicstyles', 'cleanup']},
        {name: 'paragraph', groups: ['list', 'indent', 'blocks', 'align']},
        {name: 'styles'},
        {name: 'colors'},
        {name: 'about'},
        {name: 'symbol'}
    ];
    config.removePlugins = 'templates,save,specialchar,image,flash,scayt,forms,wsc,print,iframe,pagebreak';
    CKEDITOR.plugins.addExternal('symbol', '/ckeditorplugins/symbol/', 'plugin.js');
    config.extraPlugins = 'symbol';
    config.templates_replaceContent = false;
    config.templates_files = [
        '/ckeditorplugins/templates/templates.js'
    ];
    config.allowedContent = true;
    config.toolbarCanCollapse = true;
    config.fullPage = true;
    config.skin = 'bootstrapck';
    config.height = 400;
    config.uiColor = '#f9dda0';
    config.autoParagraph = false;
    config.enterMode = CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR;
    CKEDITOR.on('instanceReady', function (ev) {
        ev.editor.dataProcessor.writer.selfClosingEnd = '>';
    });
};
```

Comment: Any chance you can contant us https://cksource.com/contact and provide access (via browser) to your website, so we could check the HTML source code and HTTP requests?

Comment: Thanks, I've set you up on the site and sent you a contact form with details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you mixed options for CKEditor and CKFinder. The second argument of `CKFinder.setupCKEditor()` is CKFinder configuration, while all `filebrowser*` options that you used belong to CKEditor configuration. Please have a look at [CKFinder.setupCKEditor() docs](http://docs.cksource.com/ckfinder3/#!/api/CKFinder-method-setupCKEditor). The third argument allows you to define upload URL parameters, so here you can point uploads to `Images`.

Please try following snippet:

```
CKFinder.setupCKEditor(ckeditor_1, {
    'height': '100%',
    'jquery': '/js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js',
    'skin': 'jquery-mobile',
    'swatch': 'a',
    'themeCSS': '/themes/mytheme.min.css'
}, {type: "Images"});
```

When using `CKFinder.setupCKEditor()` the upload path for CKEditor will be set automatically, so there should be no need to configure it explicitly.

If the above doesn't work for you, please provide also code that creates `ckeditor_1`.

Comment: That didn't help - I still get the same error. I've posted my CKEditor setup code.

Comment: Could you please post also contents of `"customConfig":"/js/ckconfig.js"` defined for CKEditor?

Comment: I've added the config file

Comment: I'd tried this on my dev and staging servers, but when I did it on my live server, it worked! No idea what was going astray - probably operator error :) Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm glad it finally worked :) It could be also some caching related issue.

Comment: @zaak, bro could you please take a look at my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45340568/how-to-change-image-save-location-in-ckeditor-drupal-7 ?